# Why does windows defender scan my computer multiple times

Tags: windows, antivirus, windows-10

Occasionally, Windows Defender sends me a notification that my device was scanned. This occurrence is quite ordinary and boring, but I actually devoted two seconds to reading the entire message once, and it says it scanned my device x times. For example, the most recent notification told me my device was scanned four times. Why is one scan not sufficient?

Comment: My guess would be that it didn't scan your device 4 times in a row, but that it scanned 4 times since you last checked it.

Answer (score 0):

On [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4026132/windows-10-schedule-a-scan-in-windows-defender-antivirus) Microsoft help page there is an explanation how to schedule tasks. Windows Defender should not scan more often than it is scheduled to scan.

It reads:

> 1. Search for and open Schedule tasks.
> 2. In the left pane, expand **Task Scheduler Library > Microsoft > Windows**, and then scroll down and select the **Windows Defender** folder.
> 3. In the top center pane, double-click Windows Defender Scheduled Scan.
> 4. ﻿In the Windows Defender Scheduled Scan Properties (Local Computer) window, select the Triggers tab, go to the bottom of the window, and then select New.
> 5. Specify how often you want scans to run and when you’d like them to
>      start.

You should also be able to check how often Windows Defender is scheduled to run now.